# Codeigniter Limit Login to Four Times a Day

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

Hello Guys I want to limit login to Four(4) per day.

I'm working like this.

Do i need to set login attempts to userdata?

anyone there done this already?

Controller

```
// database work
    $data = $this->login_model->validate_login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'));
```

Model

```
public function validate_login($username, $password) {

    $this->load->helper('password');

    $this->db->select('user_id, username, password, date_registered, active, login_attempts');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
       $row = $query->row();

       if (hash_password($password) == $row->password) {
           $array['user_id'] = $row->user_id;
           $array['username'] = $row->username;
           $array['date_registered'] = $row->date_registered;
           $array['active'] = $row->active;
           return $array;
       }
    }

    // login attempts +1 because login failed
    $this->_increase_login_attempts($username);
    return (1 + (isset($row) ? $row->login_attempts : 0));

}

private function _increase_login_attempts($username) {
        $this->db->set('login_attempts', 'login_attempts + 1', FALSE);
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->update('users');

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store the attempts count (or records if you like) in your database (e.g. MySQL, or Redis), not in session data.
Because session can be clear if a user cleared their browser cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Make another table with userId(FK, int), attemptCount (int), lastAttempt(datetime).

The logic:

1. User attempts to login
2. Check if user id exists in attempt table.

   a. If yes, check if (currentTime - lastAttempt) > 24h) reset attemptCount else attempt++.
   b. If no, create an entry, set attempt = 1.
3. Finally check if attemptCount >= 4, if yes, return error msg to user.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and post again here if i have a problem